# Using different language tags code embedded in another program

Tags: discussion, tags

Let's say I have a program that uses another language/shell commands, to do the most important aspects of said program.

Would it be bad to use the tag for the language that's doing the important aspects?

For example, I have this Ruby code:

```
puts "Hello world!"
`echo "Hello World!"`
```

This example uses [bash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby), so would it be okay to tag it with both tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the embedded language is a significant portion of the overall program, sure.  Use your discretion as to whether expertise in [bash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) would be useful for reviewing the [ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby) program.